# using column data from a framework to create new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-apply

Suppose I have the following table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7OkA.png)

I am currently using this line to create a new column:

```
MyDataFrame['PersonAge'] = MyDataFrame.apply(lambda row: "({},{})".format(row['Person'],['Age']), axis=1)
```

my goal is to have a column consisting of something like: (John, 24.0)
after that line when i MyDataFrame.head() this is the last column i see: (John, ['Age'])

This is true for all rows. for example in the next row i have: (Myla, ['Age'])
Any idea what could be the issue? I copied the column name from my table hoping it was a typo of some sort, but I got the same result.
I would appreciate any help (or a new way to make a "pair" of the previous data)! :)

Comment: Please post the data from the data frame not a picture of it.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I'm so sorry I'm new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I forgot to put row before ['Age'].
The answer should be:

```
MyDataFrame['PersonAge'] = MyDataFrame.apply(lambda row: "({},{})".format(row['Person'],row['Age']), axis=1)
```

I checked the code and this one works great! :)